# getActivity() method blocking indefinitely while unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

I'm trying to test two different `Activity` classes, where one `Activity` happens to call the other. Here's my code and then I'll explain the problem:

IntroActivityTest

```
public class IntroActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<IntroActivity> {

    IntroActivity activity;

    public IntroActivityTest() {

        super( IntroActivity.class );
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {

        super.setUp();
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    public void testIntroBypass() {

        if ( new SharedPreferencesHelper( getInstrumentation().getTargetContext() ).retrieveUserToken() == null ) {
            assertTrue( !activity.isFinishing() );
        }
        else {
            assertTrue( activity.isFinishing() );
        }
    }
}
```

RootActivityTest:

```
public class RootActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<RootActivity> {

    RootActivity activity;

    public RootActivityTest() {

        super( RootActivity.class );
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {

        super.setUp();
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    public void testInitialTab() {

        assertTrue( activity.getSupportActionBar().getSelectedTab().getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase( "Library" ) );
    }
}
```

In `IntroActivityTest`, if the user token from `SharedPreferences` is non-null, it immediately starts `RootActivity`. If it's null, it stays on `IntroActivity`. The problem is that if it is non-null, the 1st test (`IntroActivityTest`) passes, and then it hangs on the `getActivity()` method call in `RootActivityTest` and the test just freezes...no exceptions, it just hangs on that line. If the user token is null, it runs both tests completely fine.

What could be causing this? From observation, it appears that `RootActivityTest` is trying to use the `RootActivity` that was started from `IntroActivity`, but shouldn't it be starting its own instance of `RootActivity`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html):

> This class provides functional testing of a single activity. The activity under test will be created using the system infrastructure (by calling InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivity()) and you will then be able to manipulate your Activity directly.

Each ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 implementation is completely isolate and has its own life cycle which does not dependent on other ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 implementation. A testable activity must be always created via instrumentation infrastructure, not from the application under test itself. In your case, RootActivityTest will not pick up RootActivity started by IntroActivity from application and continuous running test against RootActivity. If there is a RootActivity coming from no where (not by InstrumentationTestRunner) and is brought into front, when running RootActivityTest, InstrumentationTestRunner will get confused when try to create a testable RootActivity, and simply stop and waiting for this stranger to be killed.

To test what you want, i.e. **if the user token from SharedPreferences is non-null, it immediately starts RootActivity. If it's null, it stays on IntroActivity**, you can write everything in IntroActivityTest and use [Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor.html) detecting RootActivity started from IntroActivity. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405561/test-if-a-button-starts-a-new-activity-in-android-junit-pref-without-robotium/9406087#9406087) for code sample. note that you need finish RootActivity after done testing in IntroActivityTest so that RootActivity can start properly when calling getActivity() in RootActivityTest.

Use RootActivityTest for testing everything related to RootActivity after it has been started and brought to front, for example, TextView is well rendered, button click do the right thing and etc.  In RootActivityTest, you don't need concern where and how RootActivity is started, just call getActivity() and ask instrumentation for a testable RootActivity.

Comment: Great answer! In my case, I needed to set up my monitor _before_ I called `getActivity()` because my new `Activity` was starting in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when previous test have not closed activity, and new test started the same with intent. But OS Android see that activity is already started and did not nothing, so `InstrumentationTestCase` started to wait for activity that is already tsarted